# ConstraintLayout leaking a view after removal. Bug or am I missing something?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-view, android-constraintlayout, leakcanary

I'm working on a small library which adds views dynamically (programmatically) to the view hierarchy. Then the views can be removed from the parent ViewGroup. I've noticed that when I'm adding views to the constraint layout with match parent LayoutParams and then removing the views, the views remain in the memory. It doesn't happen with FrameLayout or LinearLayout as a parent ViewGroup.
I'm using Leak Canary to detect the leak. The code that reproduces the issue (should be used in a fragment with the consraint layout as a root view):

```
private val views = mutableListOf<View>()

    fun showDefaultView() {
        repeat(5) {
            val testView = View(requireContext())
            val params = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
            (view as ViewGroup).addView(testView, params)
            views.add(testView)
        }
    }

    fun hideDefaultViews() {
        views.forEachIndexed { index, testView ->
            AppWatcher.objectWatcher.watch(testView, "testView witn index#$index")
            (view as ViewGroup).removeView(testView)
        }
        views.clear()
    }
```

So, the question. Is this a known bug? Or I just miss something? If this a known bug, is there any workaround?

Upd: I've investigated this a bit. Seems that the problem is inside the CosntraintLayout class. Sparse array mTempMapIdToWidget doesn't remove the widget (what is the "widget"? I don't know) from itself when the view is removed.

Comment: Please provide the leak trace from LeakCanary otherwise people can't help you:)